# Howto show connected targets in Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, iscsi

When I do

```
localhost:~# iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p 192.168.0.4
192.168.0.4:3260,1 iqn.2004-04.com.qnap:ts-509:iscsi.linux02.ba4731
192.168.0.4:3260,1 iqn.2004-04.com.qnap:ts-509:iscsi.linux01.ba4731
192.168.0.4:3260,1 iqn.2004-04.com.qnap:ts-509:iscsi.linux03.ba4731
localhost:~#
```

I see the available targets, but how do I see which or what target is actually connected on my CentOS5 server?

Edit:

Can can of course do this, but can't a program like `iscsiadm` tell me it instead?

```
localhost:~# ls /dev/disk/by-path/
ip-192.168.0.4:3260-iscsi-iqn.2004-04.com.qnap:ts-509:iscsi.linux02.ba4731-lun-0@  pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-0:0:0:0-part2@
pci-0000:00:1f.1-ide-0:0@                                                          pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-0:0:0:0-part3@
pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-0:0:0:0@                                                     pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-1:0:0:0@
pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1@                                               pci-0000:00:1f.2-scsi-1:0:0:0-part1@
```

Comment: on the target (server)'s side, try cat /proc/net/iet/session

Answer (score 34, accepted):

does **iscsiadm -m session** tell you what you want to know? (or I think **iscsiadm -m session -P 3** might give more info)